# Расположение курсора в шаблоне Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, шаблоны

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая переменная отвечает за расположение курсора в шаблоне PyCharm?

Т.е. есть заготовленный шаблон для пустого файла:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''Created on $DATE'''
```

При создании файла по этому шаблону курсор находится в начале файла, а надо чтобы находился в конце, на новой строчке. Т.е. так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''Created on $DATE'''
{Курсор нужен тут}
```

Мелочь, но это удобно, создал файл и сразу начал писать.
В Eclipse за это отвечает переменная `${cursor}`
Какая переменная за это отвечает в PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменной нет. Для некоторых языков позиция задается жестко в коде (например, для Java -- после имени класса).

В случае с Python курсор должен ставиться в конце файла по умолчанию. То что он ставится в начале, похоже на баг. Вы можете [создать реквест здесь](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.